# Negative number alignment in table

Tags: alignment

I know I have asked this question before but I would be really grateful if someone could explain stepwise to me how to solve the problem (instead of just posting the changed code, which I also found really really nice and helpful but I did not learn how to come to the solution on my own). The problem is probably fairly easy to solve for most of you. I have a table and I would like to have the positive and negative numbers aligned.

```
 \documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} %Doku: "scrguide"
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  % Eingabekodierung
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"
% \usepackage[english]{babel}    % Bei Bedarf: englische Sprachenunterstützung
 \usepackage{lmodern}           % Schrift: Latin Modern
 \usepackage{microtype}         % mikrotypographische Erweiterungen von pdfTeX; s.a. microtype-DE
 \usepackage{amsmath}           % AMSmath-Paket der American Mathematical Society (AMS)
 \usepackage{color}             % Verwendung von Farben 
 \usepackage{graphicx}          % Einbinden von Grafiken; Doku: "grfguide"
 \usepackage{hyperref}          % Querverweise & Links anklickbar
 \usepackage{apacite}           % Zitierregeln nach APA
 \usepackage{csquotes}          % Anführungszeichen mit \enquote{...}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 \definecolor{indigo}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}
 \definecolor{officegreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
 \definecolor{azure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
 \usepackage{float}
% --- Behübschungen
 \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
 \addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      % --''--
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  % Zeilenabstand im Text
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}     % Zeilenabstand in mehrzeiligen Formeln und Tabellen
 \setlength{\parskip}{1.3ex}           % = space between paragraphs in height of "x"
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}           % 0 pt  = indentation
 \hypersetup{                          % Gestaltung interner Links [hyperref]:
   pdfborder={0 0 0},                                           % keine Rahmen um Links
   colorlinks=true,linkcolor=azure,urlcolor=red,citecolor=blue % Links färbig hervorheben
%   colorlinks=false  % Links nicht färbig hervorheben
} % end of hypersetup`


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{makecell}


   \begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
   
   
   \caption{Ergebnisse der Schätzung über Personenparameter}
   \label{tab:personen}
   
   \scriptsize
   \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}cSSccccccc}
       &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Extraversion}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Neurotizismus} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Offenheit} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Verträglichkeit} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gewissenhaftigkeit} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}  \cmidrule(l){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11}
       &{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}\\ \toprule
       Person 1&{0.74}&{0.79}&{-0.46}&{-0.53}&  {1.08} &{1.69}& {0.39}& {0.58} &{0.83}&{1.08} \\
       Person 2&{-1.68}&{-2.07} &{0.33}&{0.40}&{-0.37}&{-0.53}&{0.10}& {0.14} &{-0.31}&{-0.50}\\
       Person 3&{1.99}&{3.28}&{-0.25}&{-0.28}& {-1.12}&{-1.38}&{-0.04}& {-0.07} &{1.20}&{1.80}\\
       Person 4&{0.74}&{0.79}&{0.72}&{0.91}&{0.81}&{1.08}&{-0.04}& {-0.07} &{-0.31}&{-0.50}\\
       Person 5&{-0.12}&{-0.21} &{-0.06}&{-0.05}&{0.15}&{0.07}& {0.39}& {0.58}&{0.83}&{1.08}\\
       Person 6 &{0.43}&{0.40} &{0.72}&{0.91}& {1.38}&{2.90}&{0.10}& {0.14} &{-0.06}&{-0.20}\\
       Person 7&{1.99}&{3.28} &{-0.90}&{-1.18}&{0.57}&{0.65}&{0.70}& {1.16} &{0.83}&{1.08}\\
       Person 8 &{-1.13}&{-1.32}&{-0.46}&{-0.53}&{0.15}&{0.07}&{0.54}& {0.84}&{0.21}&{0.14}\\
       Person 9 &{-1.40}&{-1.66}&{1.68}&{2.89}&{1.08}&{1.69}&{-0.33}& {-0.50} &{0.83}&{1.08}\\
       Person 10&{-0.62}&{-0.74}&{0.33}&{0.40}&{-1.27}&{-1.56}&{-0.78}& {-1.34} &{-0.77}&{-1.01}\\
       \bottomrule
       
\end{tabular}


\begin{tablenotes}
\item Hinweis. In der Tabelle sind lediglich die Parameter für die ersten zehn Personen dargestellt. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

   \end{document}
```

I have tried it with the column definition S but it still does not work.

Would anyone of you be so kind and help me out with this one? I am also very interested in what each of your suggested changes exactly does to the table so that I am able to change the problem on my own in the future.

Thank you very much :=)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the numbers should not be braced. Also the correct specification for the columns should be used, in this case

```
S[table-format=-1.2]
```

meaning “minus sign”, “one-digit integral part”, “two-digit fractional part”.

With `tabular*` and setting `\tabcolsep` to zero, we leave to TeX to compute the intercolumn space. It turns out that the table doesn't require to reduce the font size, provided the too wide column headers are abbreviated.

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} %Doku: "scrguide"

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Ergebnisse der Schätzung über Personenparameter}
\label{tab:personen}
   
%\footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
  l % one left aligned column
  *{10}{S[table-format=-1.2]} % ten columns with numbers
}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{E}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{N}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{O}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{V}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{G}
\\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}  \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11}
&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}&{EAP}&{WLE}
\\
\midrule
Person 1 &  0.74 &  0.79 & -0.46 & -0.53 &  1.08 &  1.69 &  0.39 &  0.58 &  0.83 &  1.08 \\
Person 2 & -1.68 & -2.07 &  0.33 &  0.40 & -0.37 & -0.53 &  0.10 &  0.14 & -0.31 & -0.50 \\
Person 3 &  1.99 &  3.28 & -0.25 & -0.28 & -1.12 & -1.38 & -0.04 & -0.07 &  1.20 &  1.80 \\
Person 4 &  0.74 &  0.79 &  0.72 &  0.91 &  0.81 &  1.08 & -0.04 & -0.07 & -0.31 & -0.50 \\
Person 5 & -0.12 & -0.21 & -0.06 & -0.05 &  0.15 &  0.07 &  0.39 &  0.58 &  0.83 &  1.08 \\
Person 6 &  0.43 &  0.40 &  0.72 &  0.91 &  1.38 &  2.90 &  0.10 &  0.14 & -0.06 & -0.20 \\
Person 7 &  1.99 &  3.28 & -0.90 & -1.18 &  0.57 &  0.65 &  0.70 &  1.16 &  0.83 &  1.08 \\
Person 8 & -1.13 & -1.32 & -0.46 & -0.53 &  0.15 &  0.07 &  0.54 &  0.84 &  0.21 &  0.14 \\
Person 9 & -1.40 & -1.66 &  1.68 &  2.89 &  1.08 &  1.69 & -0.33 & -0.50 &  0.83 &  1.08 \\
Person 10& -0.62 & -0.74 &  0.33 &  0.40 & -1.27 & -1.56 & -0.78 & -1.34 & -0.77 & -1.01 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{11}{l}{E: Extraversion; N: Neurotizismus; O: Offenheit} \\
\multicolumn{11}{l}{V: Verträglichkeit; G: Gewissenhaftigkeit}
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]